# How to put margin-bottom in a mat-table (Angular 4+)?

Tags: html, css, angular, google-chrome, mat-table

I have a table and I also have a footer. When the rows increment, the list overlaps with the footer. How can I put a margin-bottom in a table last row?

I can easily do it in Chrome inspect, but I cannot do that in HTML/CSS, since it wont read the class.

```
 <table mat-table class="marginBottom" [userSource]="users$ | async" matSort>
```

```
.marginBottom {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [last-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) pseudo-selector:

```
table:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply margin to last row of the table.
try doing

```
table tr:last-child {
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin gives you space after the table. Instead of margin you can use padding for the table to give you space before the last child.

```
marginBottom {
 padding-bottom : 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if nothing works for you then try to override the style in global css or scss i.e the styles.css in the root directory.

Whenever you need to override some default styling of angular material you should do that in the global css